# SQL update statement to replace string partially like after @ text of an email address

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-express

I want a query to update a table named users where emails are not entered properly.

Like this:

```
praneeth@gmail
ram@gmail.co
krishna@gma
farooq@gmail.com
```

I need a query to make sure that all the text after `@` is set to `gmail.com` for all the text ending with `@gma` or `@gmail.co` or `@gmail` or `gmai`

Please assist me!

BTW I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express edition.

Comment: the `UPDATE` statement syntax is fairly dependant on the RDBMS. So you can start by telling us which one you are using

Comment: What database are you using?  And how do you wan to update the records?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2008 EXPRESS edition.

Comment: Before you begin, make a backup of the table

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Email = LEFT(Email,CHARINDEX('@',Email))+'gmail.com'
WHERE Email LIKE '%@gma'
OR Email LIKE '%@gmail.co'
OR Email LIKE '%@gmail'
OR Email LIKE '%gmai'
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fe3c/1) a sqlfiddle with a demo.

And here are the results:

```
╔════════════════════╗
║       EMAIL        ║
╠════════════════════╣
║ praneeth@gmail.com ║
║ ram@gmail.com      ║
║ krishna@gmail.com  ║
║ farooq@gmail.com   ║
╚════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks for the superfast reply, I see a problem in this query.
It is updating all the email to @ gmail.com.
I have more mail id's like @yahoo.com ... 
 I want them to be intact.
Only Gmail mail must be changed.

Comment: @user3657960 Ok, I read your question the wrong way. Updated the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.
I got the answer here.

```
UPDATE TBLEmails 
SET  PersonEMail = substring(PersonEMail, 
                             1, 
                             CHARINDEX ('@', PersonEMail, 1)
                   ) + 'gmail.com' 
WHERE PersonEMail LIKE '%@gmai%'
```

This worked like a charm